# Packing structure results in return of reference to local?

Tags: c++, gcc

I've got the following code, and I'm struggling to understand why packing the structure causes a warning (and then subsequently segfault when run.) Firstly the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, std::size_t D, std::size_t S>
struct __attribute__((packed)) C {
  union __attribute__((packed)) ValueType {
    char fill[S];
    T value;
  };

  ValueType data_;

  const T& get() const {
    return data_.value;
  }

  friend
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const C& f) {
    return str << f.data_.value;
  }     
};

template <typename T, std::size_t D>
struct __attribute__((packed)) C<T, D, D> {
  T value;

  const T& get() const {
    return value;
  }

  friend
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const C& f) {
    return str << f.value;
  }    
};

template <typename T, std::size_t S = 0>
struct __attribute__((packed)) D {
  C<T, sizeof(T), S> c;
  const T& get() const {
    return c.get();
  }

  friend
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const D& f) {
    return str << f.get();
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct __attribute__((packed)) D<T, 0> {
  T v;
  const T& get() const {
    return v;
  }

  friend
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const D& f) {
    return str << f.get();
  }
};

int main(void) {
    D<int64_t> d1;
    cout << d1 << endl;
    D<int64_t, 8> d2;
    cout << d2 << endl;    
}
```

With the packing (it's GCC specific) I get the following (gcc 5.2.1/5.3.1, c++14 -Wall):

```
packed.cpp: In instantiation of ‘const T& D<T, 0ul>::get() const [with T = long int]’:
packed.cpp:58:16:   required from ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const D<long int>&)’
packed.cpp:64:13:   required from here
packed.cpp:53:12: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return v;
            ^
packed.cpp: In instantiation of ‘const T& C<T, D, D>::get() const [with T = long int; long unsigned int D = 8ul]’:
packed.cpp:40:18:   required from ‘const T& D<T, S>::get() const [with T = long int; long unsigned int S = 8ul]’
packed.cpp:45:16:   required from ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const D<long int, 8ul>&)’
packed.cpp:66:13:   required from here
packed.cpp:27:12: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return value;
```

If the structures are not packed - the code compiles normally and then runs fine (prints rubbish value - but that's expected.)

So my question is - why does packing cause a return of a temporary?

Comment: Just a guess: the description of [packed](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes) claims `In the following example struct my_packed_struct's members are packed closely together, but the internal layout of its s member is not packed—to do that, struct my_unpacked_struct needs to be packed too.` You need to pack **template T** too!? More important: you really need this attribute?

Comment: `T` is `int64_t` can't see how I can pack that? And yes, I'm trying to decode network packets that are packed in a specific way...

Comment: You took a look at [pragma pack](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Layout-Pragmas.html#Structure-Layout-Pragmas)? With alignment 1, your data are tightly packed. No gaps, no padding. And it works for [MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) compilers too.

Comment: @Youka - please add that as answer - using `pragma pack` actually fixes the problem and has the same effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [pragma pack](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Layout-Pragmas.html#Structure-Layout-Pragmas). It has the same effect as what you want, but is more common and [cross-compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx).

NOTE: Adding modified version of the code with `pragma pack`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma pack(1)    
template <typename T, std::size_t D, std::size_t S>
struct C {
  union ValueType {     
    char fill[S];
    T value;
  };

  ValueType data_;

  const T& get() const {
    return data_.value;
  }   
};
#pragma pack()       

template <typename T, std::size_t D>
struct C<T, D, D> {
  T value;

  const T& get() const {
    return value;
  } 
};

template <typename T, std::size_t D>
struct C<T, D, 0> {
  T value;

  const T& get() const {
    return value;
  } 
};

template <typename T, std::size_t S = 0>
struct D : C<T, sizeof(T), S> {
  friend
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const D& f) {
    return str << f.get();
  }
};

#pragma pack(1)    
struct E {
    D<int16_t> a;
    D<int64_t, 9> b;
};
#pragma pack()    

int main(void) {
    D<int16_t> d1;
    cout << d1.get() << ' ' << sizeof(d1) << endl;
    D<int64_t, 9> d2;
    cout << d2.get() << ' ' << sizeof(d2) << endl;  
    cout << sizeof(E) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hello Nim I just find this problem may be a gcc compiler's BUG, you can see the reference at here [enter link description here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64369)

Comment: Crap - I think you are right - this looks like the same bug! Now to find a workaround as it looks like it is unlikely to be fixed... hmm..

Comment: yes I have tried an similar but simper code to test “__attribute__((packed))” , and I get the same warning....